# How to understand steps_per_epoch in fit_generator using keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was under the impression that steps_per_epoch can be made equal to the total number of sample divided by the batch size, so that every epoch sees every sample, But the number displayed makes me think it trains on much less than that. (if i read this correctly: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly )
here is the relevant line ( i explicitly written the number of samples )

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch= 2451 // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=10)
```

But the output of the training process seems is showing numbers like 153/154, but my dataset is more than 3000 samples ).
So, in the end, what is steps_per_epoch about ? Is my model seeing all the samples at every epoch in the current state ? If not, how do i correct this ?

```
Epoch 1/10
153/153 [==============================] - 34s 225ms/step - loss: -0.4054 - dice_coef: 0.4054 - binary_accuracy: 0.2559 - acc: 0.2559
Epoch 2/10
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related enough to the question but just wanted to point it out, may it be you are filtering some data in `train_generator`? `2451` may not be the exact number of the data you are feeding into model, because some may be filtered out in `train_generator`

Comment: What is train_generator? If its a Sequence (for example ImageDataGenerator is one), then it would override your steps per epoch, as the Sequence has its own length method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that no of step should be equal to `total_dataset/batch_size` but it is not necessary to do so(you can put any no), here there are three possible cases:-

1. `No_of_step = total_dataset/batch_size` - In one epoch model will see one image(data) only once.
2. `No_of_step < total_dataset/batch_size` - model will not able to see all the images few will left out.
3. `No_of_step > total_dataset/batch_size` - some of the images will be passed more than one time in the network.

Note:- if `shuffle = True` it is hard to guess which image is left out or which is repeated.

Comment: What about the number 153 i see ? What is it representative of ? I think i am the first case you cited, but when i use the regular fit function, the output shows much higher number (ie: something like```Epoch 1/10
200/3500``` ).  instead of 
```Epoch 1/10
153/153```

Comment: @KazihiseGuy-Fernand can you tell what is the total amount of training data and the batch size you are using.

Comment: the total amount amount of training data is 2452 with  612 more samples for testing. the batch size is 16 ( from the variable BATCHSIZE, used when calling fit_generator ). Also, i am not sure if its relevant to the issue, but I have also specified a batch_size parameter when calling the flow_from_director function of imagedatagenerator. I gave it with the same value (16) using the variable BATCHSIZE.

Comment: your training data is 2452 and batch size is 16 so your no of step should be `2452 / 16 = 153.25` it is not a whole no so we must take `2452 // 16 = 153` . so there will be 153 steps and the total image seen by the model in single epoch is `153 * 16 = 2448` , here 4 images will be left out in each epoch

Comment: i get it now, Thank you for your answer and patience ! :)